# How to combine the results of multiple async calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, async-await

```
public async Task<List<string>> getAllQueries()
{ 
   List<string> allQueries = new List<string>();
   for (int i =0 ; i < 10; i++)
   {
      List<string> queries = await getQueriesForId(i);
      allQueries.AddRange(queries);
   }  
   return allQueries;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code. I am not getting the correct results. I have not much idea about async/await.  I observed that this function is returning the list without combining the results from all concurrent calls. Could somebody please let me know how to combine the lists coming from all concurrent calls and then only return ?

Comment: Try first sequential good old *Linq* algorithm (just comment out the `AsParallel().`) then *PLinq* `return Enumerable.Range(1, 10).AsParallel().Select(i => getQueriesForId(i)).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();`

Comment: Code looks perfectly correct (one would use `Task.WhenAll` to run them in parallel, but it does not make code incorrect). Please make sure to provide [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you've removed `await` - combining PLinq and `async` is not exactly trivial task to recommend (sample you have not going to help OP to get results on multiple async calls)

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) method and combine the results once they have all be materialized, consider the following:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetAllQueriesAsync()
{ 
   var tasks = 
       Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                 .Select(i => GetQueriesForIdAsync(i));

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   return tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result).ToList();
}
```

With the following snippet there are several key changes that I made.

1. Suffix `Task` and `Task<T>` returning methods with "Async"
2. Utilized `Enumerable.Range` instead of `for` loop

   - This will return a list of `IEnumerable<Task<List<string>>>`
3. Run all the queries in parallel

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `Task.WhenAll()`. I created these handy extension methods you might find useful:

```
public static Task<TResult[]> SelectAsync<T, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T> list, 
         Func<T, Task<TResult>> functionToPerform)
{
    var tasks = list.Select(functionToPerform.Invoke);
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

And here's an example how to use it:

```
var results = await myItems.SelectAsync(item => DoStuff(item)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: These both could be simplified by removing the `async` and `await` keywords, as the result is not needed within the body of the method.

Comment: @DavidPine I am not sure if the updated version without the async/await will compile. Because `Task.WhenAll<T>` returns a `Task<T[]>` and that is not a covariant type. The return type needs to be fixed (Also you forgot to remove the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` when you made the edit. I fixed the ConfigureAwait but did not change the return type)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, You're correct. I just tried to compile and it doesn't like it.

Comment: Switch it to returning `Task<TResult[]>` and it will work

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, you are correct. Nice catch, thanks! I just noticed -- Oshkosh, WI. Not too far from there, nice to see fellow WI SO folks.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain and David, I updated it again. See if that looks correct. Thanks guys!

Comment: Looks good, already gave a +1 though for the original version :)